# Alternative for std:vector to remove its elements while going through a loop?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have my loop going through vector's elements. While in this loop some of the elements are being (I want them to be) removed. Although std::vector does not allow to do this, and I would like an alternative.

```
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < rectArray.size(); j++)
{
 if( rectArray[j] == 2 ) 
  {
   rectArray.erase(rectArray.begin() + j);
  }
//...
}
```

Do you think a std::list would be good here ? Can I use something else ?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements? If not, you can quickly remove one from the middle by swapping it with `back()`, then removing it with `pop_back()`.

Comment: Note that this loop is incorrect because it skips each item after the one erased.

Comment: You code erases only every other element. Is that what you want?

Comment: @PaulManta There are some conditions in between so that is not the case you have mentioned.

Comment: @UncleBens I have slightly edited my question so that it properly show what is happening in the loop. ( more or less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest modifying your code such that it uses iterators instead of the actual vector. It's much cleaner and more efficient like this:

```
for (auto it = rectArray.begin(); it != rectArray.end(); ++it)
{
    // Access the current element with *it
    // If you want you can pass `it` and `rectArray.end()` as
    // the lower and upper bounds of the new collection,
    // rather than doing expensive resizes of the vector.
}
```

Note that `auto` is a C++11 feature (the way I used it). If your compiler supports that you might also want to use C++11's foreach:

```
for (auto it : rectArray) {
   // same as before
}
```

Comment: The first version needs a bit more work to get the correct iterator after erasing an element; the second version doesn't allow you to erase the current element within the loop at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour My suggestion was to not remove them at all but just use iterators as lower and upper bounds.

Comment: `auto` does not work for me. I had to do this : `for(std::list<CvRect>::iterator it = listOfCvRects.begin(); it != listOfCvRects.end(); it++)
 {`

Answer (score 7):

Unless the elements of the vector are very expensive to copy, the simplest is probably to `std::copy_if` (or otherwise copy the ones you want to keep) into a new vector, and then swap that with the original. There's also `remove_if` followed by `resize`.

If the elements are very expensive to relocate, then a `list` would avoid that, but it depends what else you do with the collection. If you do something else that would be cripplingly slow with a `list`, then you've just moved the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Seth: although my recommendation of it in this case might be influenced by my excitement that it's finally standard ;-)

Comment: I wonder why there is no `move_if` though... There already is `move` for ranges. Maybe they want us to simulate it with `std::make_move_iterator`, which could go horribly wrong though. :|

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for answer but as I see there is no std::copy_if now in the standard or am I wrong? (or don't have the updated libraries?) take a look here [std::copy_if is an algorithm that was dropped from the C++98 STL by accident.](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppCopy_if.htm)

Comment: @Patryk: C++11 standard is out for a few month already and most mainstream implementations updated their stdlib already, so you should find the algorithm.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ok, so I have finally went for iterators on the list but can you tell if it's worth changing for copy_if ? What advantages does it have over iterators ?

Comment: @Patryk: the advantage of `remove_if` or `copy_if` is that multiple calls to `erase` on a vector are inefficient, since every element after the erase point has to be shifted every time.

Answer (score 1):

Removing an element from the middle of a vector is expensive - because you have to move all the later elements down.

If you need to add/remove elements to the middle of a container then a list is generally better.

Answer (score 1):

List would be better than a vector - as it will not cost you anything to remove elements from the middle of the list. Removing elements from the middle of a vector, on the other hand, has linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative to `std::remove_if`. A bit faster and doesn't require a functor, however it does not maintain order.

```
auto end = std::end(rectArray);
for(auto it = std::begin(rectArray); it != end; ++it)
{
    if(it->remove_me()))    
        std::swap(*it, *--end); // or even faster *it = std::move(*--end);
}    
rectArray.erase(end, std::end(rectArray));
```

Comment: That's roughly what `remove_if` does, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that has alrdy been suggested. This solution is but a bit faster and doesn't require a functor (pre C++11).

Comment: @jrok: roughly, but `remove_if` maintains the order of the sequence, whereas this brings elements in from the end to the middle.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yea, I've alrdy updated my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a lot of deletes, a list is probably the way to go.  Here is some sample code to help.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Widget
{
public:
   explicit Widget(int someNumber);
   bool ShouldDelete();
   bool ShouldDeleteComplex(int a, int b, int c);
private:
   int _someNumber;
};

Widget::Widget(int someNumber) : _someNumber(someNumber)
{
}

bool Widget::ShouldDelete()
{
   if (_someNumber > 2)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool Widget::ShouldDeleteComplex(int a, int b, int c)
{
   if ((a * b - c) > _someNumber)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

int main()
{
   list<Widget> lw;

   lw.push_back(Widget(1));
   lw.push_back(Widget(2));
   lw.push_back(Widget(3));

   // delete from list using functor
   lw.remove_if(mem_fun_ref(&Widget::ShouldDelete));

   // delete from list using lambda function
   lw.remove_if([] (Widget& x) { return x.ShouldDeleteComplex(1, 2, 0); }   );

   vector<Widget> vw;

   vw.push_back(Widget(1));
   vw.push_back(Widget(2));
   vw.push_back(Widget(3));

   // delete using functor
   vw.erase(remove_if(vw.begin(), vw.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Widget::ShouldDelete)), vw.end());

   // delete using lambda function
   vw.erase(
      remove_if(vw.begin(), vw.end(), 
        [] (Widget& x) { return x.ShouldDeleteComplex(1, 2, 0); }
     ), 
      vw.end());

   return 0;
}
```